# How to check if application is open via Automator in MAC OS?

Tags: macos, applescript, toggle, automator

Im trying to check if an application is open via an AppleScript

This is the following code :

```
on run {input, parameters}

quit application "KeyboardViewer"


return input
end run
```

However I want it to check if KeyboardViewer is open in the first place, if it is then quit application, if not, then launch it. In a way, the code should toggle the application.

I am not familiar with coding for AppleScript (first timer here) so I would appreciate some insight.

Thanks

*edit*

I have been trying to work with it and this seems to work, is there a more efficient way ? I would like to see your inputs please

```
on run {input, parameters}

    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then

        quit application "KeyboardViewer"

    else
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"

    end if

    return input
  end run
```

There is a small (less than 1s) delay when using this script. Is there a way to make it faster ?

Comment: This code is pretty efficient in my view. Although this is another solution I used to use `if appIsRunning("Mail") then`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work :

```
on run {input, parameters}

    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then

        quit application "KeyboardViewer"

    else
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"

    end if

    return input
  end run
```

What I learned is that `if application "APPLICATION NAME" is running` checks if the application is open.